# Does Stack Overflow provide a public API to develop its app?

Tags: feature-request, api

I love Stack Overflow and would like to develop a third-party Android app for it, but does the site allows us to do so and do they provide public APIs, like [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter)?

<sub>(I am not sure if Meta Stack Overflow is the right place to ask this and feel free to migrate it.)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see https://stackapps.com/; a mostly read-only API is available.

[Version 2.1 of the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) allows you to read most aspects of a site, and with authentication allows applications to post comments.

The same site already lists some [android applications](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android).